# org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/Aware

Tags: java, spring, maven, noclassdeffounderror

In my maven build, I get the below error

> Fatal error during compilation org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/beans/factory/Aware

From Dependency Tree i noticed

**(org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.1.4.RELEASE)**

In my pom.xml, I added the following dependency, yet the error doesn't seem to go

```
<spring.version>3.1.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
        <artifactId>grails-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${grails.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
        <artifactId>grails-plugin-testing</artifactId>
        <version>${grails-test-plugin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
        <artifactId>grails-test</artifactId>
        <version>${grails-test-plugin.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat</artifactId>
        <version>${grails.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>cache</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>${grails.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>filterpane</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>console</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>resources</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.6</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>database-migration</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>jawr</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.3</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>0.8</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>yui-minify-resources</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.4</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>webxml</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>richui</artifactId>
        <version>0.8</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Please help

Comment: Upto to my knowledge we should find a dependency which is using spring-beans that should exclude.

Comment: You are using spring version 3.1.3 RELEASE but the dependency is also looking for 3.1.4 RELEASE for spring-beans.jar. This ensures that the given jar is omitted and therefore you are getting this error. Check your pom.xml to look for 3.1.4 RELEASE